# Операция, обратная побитовому ИЛИ

Tags: битовые-операции

хотелось бы узнать, существует ли способ восстановить исходные значения из результата побитового ИЛИ? То есть, что я имею ввиду:

```
0111 1100 0101 
| 
1101 1111 1001
```

в результате дает `1111 1111 1101`, так вот, имея результат, и одно из исходных чисел, можно ли восстановить второе? То есть:

```
1111 1111 1101
*какая-то операция*
0111 1100 0101
```

и в результате `1101 1111 1001`?

Comment: Это невозможно. Для подобных преобразований можно пользоваться XOR

Comment: @АлексейР, а можно немного подробнее? Не совсем понимаю, как его тут применить

Comment: Можно ли по сумме восстановить слагаемые?

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно не существует.

`1 | x === 1` независимо от значения `x`. Так что по результату (`1`) и значению одного исходного числа (`1`) вы не можете вычислить `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Побитовая операция OR является необратимой с точки зрения восстановления исходного числа, зная маску и результат. А операция XOR, напротив, обратимой. Для доказательства рассмотрим таблицы истинности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблицы истинности OR и XOR отличаются только последней строкой, где `1 OR 1 == 1`, а `1 XOR 1 == 0`. В остальном таблицы истинности идентичны.
Но это отличие и делает операцию OR необратимой, а XOR – обратимой.

Обратимость означает, что, зная сочетание бита маски и бита результата, можно однозначно вычислить бит исходного числа. Но, поскольку для операции OR одному и тому же сочетанию бита маски и бита результата 1 и 1 соответствует сразу 2 разных бита – 0 и 1 – исходного числа, то однозначность теряется. В таблице истинности операции XOR все сочетания битов маски битов результата уникальные, поэтому в этом случае неоднозначности нет и операция обратима.

Пример шифрования и расшифровки числа с помощью [XOR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%C2%AB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%C2%BB)

```
src = 0b011111000101
print(f'Исходное число:\t\t{src:012b}')
mask = 0b110111111001
print(f'Маска шифр.:\t\t{mask:012b}')
res = src ^ mask  # применяем операцию XOR к исходному числу и маске
print(f'Зашифрованное:\t\t{res:012b}')
out = res ^ mask  # повторно применяем операцию XOR к зашифрованному числу и той же маске
print(f'Расшифрованное:\t\t{out:012b}')
```

```
Исходное число:     011111000101
Маска шифр.:        110111111001
Зашифрованное:      101000111100
Расшифрованное:     011111000101
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1111 1111 1101
*какая-то операция*
0111 1100 0101
```

Тут можно точно сказать только насчёт тех битов, где в одном из чисел, к которым применялось `ИЛИ` был `0`. В этих битах во втором числе содержится то же, что и в результате:

```
1??? ??11 1?0?
```

Про остальные биты мы не можем ничего сказать.